# Error: Unsupported Terraform Core version

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a simple terraform configuration as follows.

```
# Terraform settings Block
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm" # https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features { }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}
```

When I run

```
terraform init
```

I get the following error.

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported Terraform Core version
│
│   on main.tf line 3, in terraform:
│    3:   required_version = "~> 1.0.0"
│
│ This configuration does not support Terraform version 1.2.2. To proceed, either choose another supported Terraform version or update this version
│ constraint. Version constraints are normally set for good reason, so updating the constraint may lead to other errors or unexpected behavior.    
╵
```

If the required version is set the following way, it works fine(Changed ~> to >=).

```
required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
```

Looked at [this doc](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/versions?in=terraform/1-0#review-example-configuration), but not clear what to do. Should I revert back to **required_version = ">= 1.0.0"**

Just wanted to ensure that lastest minor is in place. Also read somewhere that for production, the one with tilde(~) is recommended. Bit confused now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have already installed TF version `1.2.2`, which obviously is far newer then  `1.0.0`. If you want to use such an old version of TF, you have [download older version](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/) of terraform, and use that to run your scripts.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. When I use this: "required_version = "~> 1.0"", instead of "required_version = "~> 1.0.0"" (removed last 0), its working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading both the terraform and the `azurerm` terraform provider to the latest versions (up to the date of writing this answer):

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" { }

  required_version = "1.2.5"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.14.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to fix the issue locally by using an older version of terraform (1.2.3 instead of 1.2.5), so I'm guessing the issue you experienced is similar to mine.

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" { }

  required_version = "1.2.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.14.0"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when running terraform in a `ubuntu 20.04` agent in Azure DevOps pipelines the exact same provider configuration, I was still getting the same error (for some weird reason - a bug maybe? - the pipeline would try to use terraform `1.2.4`, when I locked it to `1.2.3`) ... I was able to fix it by using the same versions with `>=` :

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" { }

  required_version = ">=1.2.3"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.14.0"
    }
  }
}
```